Nginx add header in http-section with variable value set in location-section
In my nginx setup, I'm adding some http-headers globally within the http-section. One specific header however depends on a value that I only know after mapping the location block.
When I add the add_header directive within the location block, all headers from the http-section need to be listed again as they won't be inherited. This is as-intended as stated in the docs:

These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no add_header directives defined on the current level.

To get around this, I tried to define the header in the http-section with a variable value, and used a map to initialize the variable (as set is not allowed on http level, see the docs). I then set the variable to another value within the location block:
http {
    map "" $my_header {
        default "A";
    }

    add_header X-My-Header $my_header;

    # ...

    server {
        # ...
        location /myLocation {
            set $my_header "B";
            # ...
        }
    }
}

This, however, will not work - X-My-Header will always have the value A.
Is there any way to do this (without using add_header directly in location and therefore the need to repeat or include all other headers set in http as well)?
And, just for educational reasons, why is my attempt not working as expected?

You can't change mapped variable. But you can use set in server block instead of map.

@AlexeyTen that explains why it's not working then. And yes, but I cannot use set in http-block, which is where I set the headers.

Why do you want to add header in http instead of server?

@AlexeyTen Because they're needed in all server entries.

You could use map with second variable.
http {
    map $my_header $my_real_header {
        default $my_header;
        ''      A;
    }

    add_header X-My-Header $my_real_header;

    # ...

    server {
        # ...
        location /myLocation {
            set $my_header B;
            # ...
        }
    }
}

Here, if $my_header is empty (or not set) $my_real_header will be A, but if $my_header is not empty, $my_real_header will contain value of $my_header.

I actually tried something similar before, and I got (adjusted to your variable names here) nginx: [emerg] unknown "my_header" variable after adding this when I test the config with nginx -t. This was the reason I tried to initialize the variable with the map directive.
If this is actually working for you, do you have any idea why it doesn't for me? Matter of nginx version?

I just tried again, with your example exactly, and can confirm: I get the error message I quoted above. Nginx version is 1.18

@JohannesH. Do you have set $my_header ...; somewhere? It works on my default setup. See update.

@JohannesH. check than you don't mistype $my_header in map directive on both places.

In fact I was trying to add the map first, without setting the value anywhere. I did not expect nginx to treat variables differnet when they're not set anywhere than when they're set somewhere in the configuration at all, I kind of was assuming declaring them in an inner block is the same to "the outside" than not declaring them at all. After adding an arbitrary set somewhere as a test, the error did indeed not pop up anymore.
I'll mark your answer as accepted.

It's btw more performant to map the empty string ("") to the default value (A), and default to $my_header, as no regexp lookup is needed this way, while the logic stays the same. In case you want to improve the answer.

One option to avoid repeating the same configuration is to use include for the common headers.
http {
    include common-headers.conf;
    add_header X-My-Header "A";
    # ...
    server {
        # ...
        location {
            include common-headers.conf;
            add_header X-My-Header "B";
            # ...
        }
    }
}


Thank you for your answer! I'm aware that would be an option, but as stated in the question, I'd prefer if there was another solution.
